# Putting the runFormPost widget into a tuple

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to provide some context for the widgets (Html Forms) that are being generated by `runFormPost`. I thought I can simply stick the result into a Tuple with my context and pattern match it in my Hamlet but it turning out to be challenging because of Handler Monads.

I have a Monadic form with the following type signature:

```
myForm :: ModelId -> Model -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult MyData, Widget)
myForm rid rec extra = do
     -- whamlet code here
```

I render a series of forms inside `forM` and use the list of widgets in my Hamlet file. It all works fine.

```
widgets <- forM rs' $ \(Entity rid rec) ->
          runFormPost $ myForm rid rec
```

Now, I would like to add some data to each widget and return it as a tuple. For this simple example, let's assume I want to add a String. I tried the following code and it does not compile when I try to use it in my Hamlet file (it compiles if I don't use `widgets` list in my Hamlet file)

```
widgets <- forM rs' $ \(Entity rid rec) ->
          return ("Test", runFormPost $ myForm rid rec)
```

In my Hamlet file, I tried something like this (`x` is my String context):

```
$forall (x,((res,widget), enctype)) <- widgets
     <div>
        <form method=post action=@{HandlerR hId} enctype=#{enctype}>
           ^{widget}
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `((t0, a1), a0)'
            with actual type `Handler ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)'
Expected type: [(t1, ((t0, a1), a0))]
  Actual type: [(t1,
                 Handler ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype))]
In the second argument of `Data.Foldable.mapM_', namely `widgets'
```

So far I have tried using `fmap` and `liftM` inside `forM or map` but I keep getting a similar error. I also tried throwing `Handler` in my pattern match which gave me an error saying `Handler` not in scope.

Any thoughts on how I can append some additional piece of info to a widget and re-use it in my Hamlet file?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's my first guess: the problem is that `runFormPost` yields a result which is wrapped in a monad, `Handler` in this case: `widgets :: (String, Handler ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)`. So, you should use the unwrapped version `widgets` which you defined at first, to add your additional information. Using your first version of `widgets  :: ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)`, you can then add the line `let widgetsWithInfo = map (\w -> ("test", w)) widgets`. In your hamlet file, you should then use `widgetsWithInfo :: (String, ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype))`.

Comment: @ichistmeinname it works great... thank you! Could you please post this as a response so I can accept your answer? Also, it will be great if you help me understand why using something like `fmap` does not work. For example, if I do `fmap (\x -> ("Test", x)) runFormPost $ myForm rid rec` wouldn't fmap unwrap runFormPost and then package it back? Is this because of stacked Monads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `runFormPost` yields a result which is wrapped in a monad, `Handler` in this case.

```
widgets :: (String, Handler ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)
```

So, you should use the unwrapped version widgets which you defined at first, to add your additional information. Using your first version of `widgets :: ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)`, you can then add the line

```
let widgetsWithInfo = map (\w -> ("test", w)) widgets
```

In your hamlet file, you should then embed `widgetsWithInfo :: (String, ((FormResult MyData, Widget), Enctype)`.

To your additional question: Your intention with `fmap` seems right to me, but (if it's not just a typo) your expression is parenthesised incorrect. You want to apply `fmap` to the result of `runFormPost $ myForm rid rec`, so you have to parenthesise that subexpression:

```
fmap (\x -> ("Test", x)) (rumformPost $ myForm rid rec)
```